# Smooth Animation Troubles

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I have a button that I am trying to animate to signify sort of a drop down menu effect. Similar to what is seen here

https://medium.com/@phillfarrugia/building-a-tinder-esque-card-interface-5afa63c6d3db

I have used the CGAffineTransform property and converted the degrees to radians to properly rotated. However, the problem comes when I rotate it back the other way. Instead of going back the direction it came it just does somewhat of a akward flip back into the same position.

Could anyone help me rrecreate this smoother transition that is seen in the link I provided

Here is my current code.

```
@objc func showCalendarPressed(){
    print("show calendar pressed")
    //will check if there has been any animation work done on the UIVIEW
    if self.showCalendar.transform == .identity {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5) {
            self.showCalendar.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: self.radians(degrees: 180) )

        }

    }else {
        //there is a transform on it and we need to change it back
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            //will remove the transform and animate it back
            self.showCalendar.transform = .identity
        }) { (true) in

        }
    }
}
```

Radians Function

```
func radians(degrees: Double) -> CGFloat{
    return CGFloat(degrees * .pi / 180)
}
```

Comment: Please add your `radians(degrees:)` method to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going exactly 1/2 way around (maybe slightly more depending on your conversion to `radians`), and when you return to `.identity`, it keeps going the same direction because that is closer (the direction with least rotation). Try using a slightly smaller angle initially.  I found this to work:

Replace:

```
self.radians(degrees: 180)
```

with:

```
self.radians(degrees: 179.999)
```

By going just slightly less than 1/2 way around (which will be imperceptible), returning to `.identity` will rotate the direction it came from.

Comment: in the else statement

Comment: No, replace your initial rotation of 180.